# Monte Carlo importance sampling in statistical physics finite approximation question

Tags: thermodynamics, statistics

I am trying to understand a formula found in "Topics in Current Physics: Monte Carlo Methods in Statistical Physics Springer-Verlag" attributed to L. D. Fosdick methods comp physics 1963. I can't get my hands on the original paper and I don't understand this formula at all.

Thermodynamic average of some observable $\mathcal{O}(\sigma)$ can be defined as
 \begin{align}
    \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle = \frac{\int_\sigma \mathcal{O}(\sigma) e^{-\beta H} d\sigma}{\int_\sigma  e^{-\beta H} d\sigma}
\end{align}

and using importance sampling with probability $\mathbb{P}(\sigma)$ one can apparently use L. D. Fosdicks formula to reduce this in the finite problem to
\begin{align}
    \langle \mathcal{O} \rangle \approx \mathcal{O} =  \frac{\sum_\sigma \mathcal{O}(\sigma) \mathbb{P}^{-1}(\sigma) e^{-\beta H} }{\sum_\sigma \mathbb{P}^{-1}(\sigma)  e^{-\beta H}}
\end{align}

I have a few issues with this, firstly I don't understand what $\mathbb{P}^{-1}(\sigma)$ represents, and I can't seem to get my hands on the original paper or understand how this works. Any references/help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to dig out Fosdick's old paper, since the formula is the standard starting point for importance sampling. Rigorous introductions can be found in many books, for example *Simulation and the Monte Carlo Method* by RY Rubinstein, and in online resources such as [these notes](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/mc/), as well as books on molecular simulation. There's a tag covering importance sampling at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/importance-sampling).

I'll just give a hand-waving explanation. The thermodynamic (canonical ensemble) average that you start with is a ratio of integrals: the denominator acts as a normalization to convert the Boltzmann factor $e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}$ into a probability density. However it is convenient to keep both the integrals as they are. Then, one can imagine evaluating the ratio of integrals by sampling the states uniformly, ending up with a ratio of sums
$$
\langle \mathcal{O}\rangle \approx \frac{c\sum_{\sigma=1}^N \mathcal{O}(\sigma)e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}}{c\sum_{\sigma=1}^N e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}}
=
\frac{\sum_{\sigma=1}^N \mathcal{O}(\sigma)e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}}{\sum_{\sigma=1}^N e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}} .
$$
The factor $c$ involved in going from integrals to sums cancels.
If the states $\sigma$ were sampled on a regular grid (for example, coordinates of all the particles, each discretized on a grid of spacing $\delta$ in a range $0\ldots L$) this would amount to a simple quadrature formula, and $N$ would be $(L/\delta)$ raised to a power given by the number of particles multiplied by the dimensionality of the system. But equally well, we can sample the states *randomly* (as long as we do the sampling uniformly) and the formula will be the same. In that case, $N$ is just the total number of states sampled. This is "crude Monte Carlo", and is rarely a practical approach in statistical mechanics, as most randomly sampled states will have a vanishingly small Boltzmann factor.

The importance sampling approach assumes that we have sampled the points *non-uniformly* in some way. Let $P(\sigma)$ be proportional to the probability density of sampling state $\sigma$. We choose this function: we just need to ensure that it is nonzero everywhere that makes a contribution to the integral. There is no need to normalize $P(\sigma)$, since it will appear in both numerator and denominator. In fact, I'd like to interpret $P(\sigma)$ as the number of times we visit state $\sigma$. In that case, we simply need to divide the contribution of state $\sigma$ to the estimate of the integral, by $P(\sigma)$. The more frequently visited states will be sampled with better statistics than the less frequently visited states: by adding all the contributions from state $\sigma$, and dividing by $P(\sigma)$, we ensure that we don't introduce a bias by changing the way we do the sampling. So the formula becomes
$$
\langle \mathcal{O}\rangle \approx 
\frac{\sum_{\sigma=1}^N P(\sigma)^{-1}\mathcal{O}(\sigma)e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}}{\sum_{\sigma=1}^N P(\sigma)^{-1} e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}} .
$$
where now the sum is over $N$ states which have been sampled in a nonuniform way.

A common choice is $P(\sigma)\propto e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}$,
which concentrates the sampling in areas where the Boltzmann factor is high, and the formula becomes simply
$$
\langle \mathcal{O}\rangle \approx 
\frac{\sum_{\sigma=1}^N \mathcal{O}(\sigma)}{\sum_{\sigma=1}^N 1} =
\frac{\sum_{\sigma=1}^N \mathcal{O}(\sigma)}{N} .
$$
The Boltzmann factor hasn't really disappeared: it is hidden in the way we have sampled the $N$ states. Metropolis-Hastings is the most common way to do this sampling, and it only requires a knowledge of the un-normalized weights, $P(\sigma)$, since it just calculates ratios of them when deciding whether to accept a move from one state to another.

I'll just reiterate, I have been far too sloppy in the above description to satisfy any respectable expert in the field, but I hope this gives a picture of what is happening.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thanks alot for your time @LonelyProf this helped a lot. I obviously lack some understanding of statistical physics and should probably spend some time going over these some more.